# jstack unable to attach to java pid

Tags: java, cassandra

jps/jstat/jstat is unable to find or attach to java pid (owned by Cassandra user).
I tried the soft link sudo ln -s /tmp/hsperfdata_cassandra/`cat /var/run/dse/dse.pid` /tmp/hsperfdata_`cat /var/run/dse/dse.pid` -- didn't help.

i am running java 1.8.0_45-b14 on ubuntu 14.04

Any comments or suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using versoin 2.2+.

Cassandra 2.2.0 added JVM option `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` to improve performance. If you want to use jps or such, you need to remove that option or use `ps` and find pid.

From the patch in [CASSANDRA-9483](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9483):

`- The default JVM flag -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem will cause the following tools JVM     to stop working: jps, jstack, jinfo, jmc, jcmd as well as 3rd party tools like Jolokia.     If you wish to use these tools you can comment this flag out in cassandra-env.{sh,ps1}`

(I just noticed the change is in 2.2.0 but NEWS.txt update is only in 3.0+. I will make sure NEWS.txt is updated in next 2.2 release.)

Comment: I can run jps, jstack on a standalone sandbox node, but can't attach the pid in prod/pre-prod environments.

Comment: this option is not available in cassandra-env,sh. Besides, I can get the pid, but jstack -l <pid> -- reports no such process; same setup works in sandbox environment.

Comment: is performance really improved with this option? unfortunately this completly disables monitoring for me.